# How to get rid of these 'pseudo-planes'?

Tags: geometry

I often make small mistakes when extruding geometry for example when extruding walls for a house. Sometimes this creates double geometry. I know I can get rid of this using W > remove doubles.
In this case I can't seem to get rid of this faulty geomtry (see screenshot). Somehow, these 3 vertices seem connected with a plane that I didn't create. I tried Remove Doubles, Dissolve, Delete etc... but nothing works.

Can someone tell me how to clean these problems please? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: It may be the face of a non-planar n-gon. Could you check the nearby faces?

Comment: There is indeed a non-planar face. When I go to face selection, I can select that whole corner as one face, which doesn't make sense. I think the mistake was caused by extruding everyting downwards. Is it possible to clean this up or should I just delete the whole thing?

Comment: in face select mode select that triangle and delete it.

Comment: You try selecting everything in Edit Mode, then Press W and select the Remove doubles option.

Comment: @cegaton, the triangle is not recognised as a face

Comment: @Tejas, I already did this. I am under the impression that the remove doubles option is unable to solve all the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a lot from your image but this might be just a big n-gon, so maybe you can try selecting these two vertices marked in red and pressing J to create a line. 
*(it will probably solve it by completing the box shape)*

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had to do some more deleting and redrawing but your tip got me on the right track.